# Downgrade Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am using Xcode 9.4 , Swift 4.1 . I recently updated my pod file by mistake and it update all frameworks in it which is causing errors. I want to revert some frameworks back to their previous versions. Removing and reinstalling them is installing their latest versions. How can I force to install previous version? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Specify the required version in your pod file.

Comment: My pod was earlier simply 'mypod'. Which later changed to 2.x.1 and nowchanged to 2.x.y, so when i simply install mypod  it automatically installs 2.x.2

Comment: @shravani As Paulw11 said, specify the pod version you want to use: `pod 'mypod', '2.0.0'`